# Append .htm to any url with or without extension

Tags: .htaccess

im trying to append .htm extension to url that dont have any extension, but i dont have any results
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.htm -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^.*$ $1.htm [R=301,L]
```

any tip?

Thank you

Comment: What if the REQUEST_URI is `/subdir/`? I don't think you want it to become `subdir/.htm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1 is for groups, what you need is something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.htm [R=301,L]
```

but to match paths without the extension you need change the expression to something more close to your reality. for example this:

```
http://domain.com/a.b.c.d
```

d is a extension or not? maybe the right expression is ^([^.]+)$ to find any path without the . character.